# How to Add column A and B in Column C in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I just want to add the column A and B into c column as parameter in between the single quotes

Comment: I'm not sure where you'd insert A but essentially `=UPDATE S SET color_code = '" & B1 & "' FROM table S WHERE ISNULL(color_code,'" & B1 & "') = AND store_mdname='table'"`

Comment: If you want a more thorough answer you'll need to provide more detail for the question

Comment: I tried the above, but it's throwing formula error

Comment: whoops lost the quote at the beginning `"=UPDATE S SET color_code = '" & B1 & "' FROM table S WHERE ISNULL(color_code,'" & B1 & "') = AND store_mdname='table'"

Comment: I tried as mentioned, but now it's not showing the data in the A & B column data in the C column it's just showing me the column number.

Comment: "=UPDATE S SET color_code = ' " & B71 & " ' FROM tblstoremeta S WHERE ISNULL(color_code,' " & B71 " ') = '' AND store_mdname = ' " & A71 & " ' "

Comment: Must have been another typo by @Marcucciboy2. The quotation mark has to go after the initial equal sign: `="UPDATE S SET color_code = ' " & B71 & " ' FROM tblstoremeta S WHERE ISNULL(color_code,' " & B71 & " ') = '' AND store_mdname = ' " & A71 & " ' "`

Comment: Just check that the logic of combining text and cell values is as follows: `="text1" & A1 & "text2" & B1 & "text3" & C1 & "text4" ...`

Comment: Thank you so much @DattelKlauber for your help. It was very helpful and it saved much time.

Comment: Thank you so much @Marcucciboy2 for your help. It was very helpful and it saved much time.

Comment: No problem! Just fyi next time I would recommend adding more context to your question to bring more eyes to it

Comment: Alright noted @Marcucciboy2